# The List<T> returns NULL even when being populated in the Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a game, I'm creating a simple coin spawner with the following code, where the first time instantiation is successful, but the other times the list containing a list of spawn points returns null. The spawn new object is called when the player has steps on an object after which it is destroyed.

Code:

```c#
public class SpawnManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> SpawnableItems;
    public List<SpawnPrefab> SpawnPoints;
    public float SeismosAvailable = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        SpawnNewSeismos();
    }

    public void SpawnNewSeismos()
    {
        int spawnPointRandom = Random.Range(12, 21);

        SpawnPrefab x = SpawnPoints[spawnPointRandom]; //<--- RETURNS NULL WHEN CALLED AGAIN

        if (x == null) { Debug.Log("x is null. Now What?"); }

        if(x!=null)
        x.RequestSpawn(SpawnableItems[0]);
    }
}
```

SpawnPrefab is another script which instantiates gameobjects from its position, and each spawnpoint has this script attached to it. Here's an image of the list being populated in the editor:

[image: Screenshot from the editor]

I didn't include the other spawn functions included in the same script that spawns enemies but they do use the same list SpawnPoints, but from range (0, 3) which are called from the `Update()` function.

Any form of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered populating the list in code instead?

Comment: Based off of the coloring in your inspector it appears this may be some form of prefab, have you determined that you only have one of this object in the scene?  and did you apply this change to your prefab?

Comment: In your code `SpawnPoints` is null because it is declared but never initialized. You have to do `SpawnPoints = new List<SpawnPrefab>()` and also add items to it before you can do `SpawnPrefab x = SpawnPoints[spawnPointRandom];`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Unity automatically initializes it when deserializing the script for use in the inspector. Hibnu has already shown that the array is populated with values, what's `null` *is those values* when he tries to read them (not the array).

Comment: @Hibnu: I suspect you are destroying the spawn points somewhere, given that "it works the first time."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support. As @Eddge suggested, the issue was with a new prefab unable to populate items when instantiated. The first instantiation happened without any flaws for some reason. So, I was able to fix it by altogether removing the manager as a prefab, and access the manager directly with a tag. Thanks a lot everyone.